# Cypress: This data is Undefined - Test cannot locate data in BDD testing but, can locate data under Mocha framework

Tags: automated-tests, mocha.js, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I'm trying to run a test using BDD.  It will open the test page however when I ask it to go into the page object that contains some test data I get the following message from the cypress console.

The funny thing is I've run this test BEFORE adding as a plain mocha test with page objects.  This code runs end to end perfectly.

So where is this error coming from?

[image]

BDD test scenario

Scenario: User can purchase items and have them delivered to shipping address

```
Given I am on the Ecommerce page
When I add the mobile handsets to the shopping cart
And I verify the total price of shopping cart
Then I select the checkout button
When I will select my shipping location
And I agree to the terms and conditions checkbox
When I select the Purchase button
Then I will see an alert stating my order was successful, plus an ETA delivery
```

Step definition file

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />

import { Given,When,Then,And } from "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps";
import Homepage from "../../../support/pageObjects/Homepage";
import orderSummaryPage from "../../../support/pageObjects/orderSummaryPage";
import completeOrderPage from "../../../support/pageObjects/completeOrderPage";
 
const homepage = new Homepage()
const StartCheckout = new orderSummaryPage()
const CompleteOrder = new completeOrderPage()
 
Given ( 'I am on the Ecommerce page', () => {
 
    cy.visit(Cypress.env('url')+"/angularpractice/")
    
    })
 
When('I add the mobile handsets to the shopping cart',function () {
 
        homepage.getShopTab().click() 
    
        this.data.mobileHandset.forEach(function(element) {// this custom commad will add items to your cart
    
              cy.AddToCart(element)  
            }); 
    
    
    StartCheckout.getBasketCheckoutButton().click()
    
    } )//end of step 
 
And('I verify the total price of shopping cart',() => {
 
    //calculate shopping cart here
    let sum=0
       
    CompleteOrder.getProductCost().each(($e1, index, $list) =>{
    
      const unitCost=$e1.text()  
      let res= unitCost.split(" ") 
      res= res[1].trim() 
      sum=Number(sum)+Number(res)
      
    }).then(function() 
    {
      cy.log(sum)
    
    })
    
    CompleteOrder.getBasketTotalCost().then(function(element)
    {
      const shopCartTotal=element.text()  
      var res= shopCartTotal.split(" ") 
      var total= res[1].trim() 
      expect(Number(total)).to.equal(sum)
    
    })
    
    
    } )//end of step
 
Then('I select the checkout button',() => {
 
    StartCheckout.getStartCheckoutButton().click()
 
} )//end of step
 
When('I will select my shipping location',() => {
 
    CompleteOrder.getShippingCountry().type('United Kingdom')
    CompleteOrder.getShippingCountryConfirm().click()
 
} )//end of step
 
And('I agree to the terms and conditions checkbox',()=> {
 
    CompleteOrder.getTermsConditionsCheckbox().click({force: true})
 
})//end of step 
 
When('I select the Purchase button',()=> {
 
    CompleteOrder.getPurchaseButton().click()
 
})
 
Then('I will see an alert stating my order was successful, plus an ETA delivery',()=> {
 
    CompleteOrder.getPurchaseAlert().then(function(element){
 
      
        const actualText= element.text()
       expect(actualText.includes('Success')).to.be.true
    
      }) 
 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) create a new `this` scope and that is probably why you cannot access `this.data` - which is in the global scope for the `when` scenario. Try replacing them with plain functions.

> The funny thing is I've run this test BEFORE adding as a plain mocha test with page objects. This code runs end to end perfectly.

This I have seen in cypress tests. If I want to add a variable in the global scope - I need to do it in a `before` block. Probably it is part of the asynchronous way cypress works.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me is to swap `function` in the step for ` =>` instead and it will be able to go into the data.   Is that right?

Comment: That should give you access to the global `this` yes. From there you would need to set it properly

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to fix this problem.  I was still experiencing issues after attempting the previous answer.  So I added the following to access the data from fixtures (see line that is underscored).

[image]

I then modified the test step definition code that contained the data to this:

```
When('I add the mobile handsets to the shopping cart', () =>{
 
        homepage.getShopTab().click() 
    
        data.mobileHandset.forEach(function(element) {// this custom commad will add items to your cart
    
              cy.AddToCart(element)  
            }); 
    
    
    StartCheckout.getBasketCheckoutButton().click()
    
    } )//end of step
```

Once I did that, cypress was able to access my code and it ran successfully.

for some reason using `this` for data in cypress mocha works fine but for some unknown reason if I used `this` in Cypress BDD it stopped working.

This is a good alternative for anyone else trying to retrieve data in cypress BDD.